# How to save executing time of select list from multi conditions

Tags: matrix, filtering

I have a matrix:

```
`MT={{1, 54, 55}, {2, 841, 5}, {3, 6, 65}, {4, 28, 328}, {5, 188, 21}, {6, 2, 887}, {7, 36, 32}, {8, 7, 2}}`
```

And i need select the list which the 1st Raw `WL={1,5,7,8}`

The result will be `{{1, 54, 55}, {5, 188, 21}, {7, 36, 32}, {8, 7, 2}}`

But I want to save the executing time from the code:

`Catenate[Table[
  Select[MT, #[[1]] == WL[[i]] &], {i, Dimensions[WL][[1]]}]]`

By this method, when `Dimension[WL]` too long, the executing time also become longer.

Does any method or function can easily save the executing time from this case?

Comment: `MT[[WL]]`will do it for your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Cases`

```
Cases[{Alternatives @@ WL, __}] @ MT
```

> {{1, 54, 55}, {5, 188, 21}, {7, 36, 32}, {8, 7, 2}}